# CREATE SCHEMA gives 1064 error

Tags: sql, mysql, mysql-error-1064

```
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `paragraph` 
   DEFAULT CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE default collation ;
```

this line results with error 1064. MySql 5.4.3-beta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works:

```
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `paragraph` 
   DEFAULT CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE default;
```

There was an extra "collation" at the end.

Comment: Thanks, strange Workbench generate me this

Comment: @dynback.com: Strange: Normally I report issues in a bug-tracker of the software, not on Stackoverflow. :)